# Nginx настроить перенаправление при ошибке 404

Tags: nginx

В конфигурационном файле есть

```
location / {
    location ~* ^.+\.(webp|css|js|woff2|svg|png|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        expires modified +1w;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
}
```

Что необходимо добавить, в случаи если страница отдает

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL****
```

Отдать код 404, сообщить что данной страницы не существует. И тут же переадресовать на главную страницу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Отдать код 404, сообщить что данной страницы не существует. И тут же переадресовать на главную страницу.» — какое-то противоречивое требование

Comment: Страница отдает 404 код, то есть php тут не работает. Для таких случаев, еще до подгрузки php. Как в конфиге выставить правило, которое будет срабатывать когда будет отдавать дефолтную страницу 404.

Comment: У вас в обоих location написано, что в случае несуществующего файла нужно отдать `@fallback`. Я на 146% уверен что это будет PHP. Ну и ещё раз: или 404 или редирект (302). Одновременно не бывает.

Comment: `error_page 404 = @fallback;`  в случаи ошибки, мы што та тут делаем, не силен в Nginx. Вот если у нас 404, как выполнить переадресацию, просто переадресовать. Сообщить что страница отдает 404 и перенаправить пользователя на другую без кода 301 и тд

Comment: У меня ощущение что вы не понимаете как работает http. Сформулируйте в вопросе какую проблему вы собственно решаете?

Comment: @Aleks если страница динамическая, то знать о ее существовании или нет может только приложение. Поэтому вебсервер здесь будет безсилен. В этом случае пусть ваше приложение показывает кастомную страничку и отдает 404 код ответа. А на ней добавьте JS код, который потом отредиректит куда вам надо. Пример тут https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-bom/javascript-redirect/

Comment: `error_page 404 /?do=404;` добавил в блок `location` перезагрузил сервер. Если по адресу site.ru/?do=404, отдает верно страницу. То когда возникает ошибка `Not Found The requested URL /seriaд was not found on this server.` Мне по прежнему отдает дефолтную страницу, в чем тут дело?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скриншет той самой страницы с которой рассчитываю перенаправлять пользователя или хотя бы выставить заглушку...

Comment: К стати в php когда контент не найден, я сперва отдаю ошибку, затем перенаправляю пользователя `http_response_code(404); die(header("Location: ".URL_SITE))`

Comment: « Ну и ещё раз: или 404 или редирект (301/302). Одновременно не бывает.»

Comment: `error_page 404 /?do=404;` Из-за чего может правило неработать?

Comment: error_page 404 =200 /index.html;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то тут или 404 на стороне nginx или редирект, но можно 404 + редирект через заданное время на JS или PHP. Например на странице обработки 404-ой ошибки:

На JS:

```
<head>
    ....
    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = "https://yandex.ru";
        }, 3000); // Задержка 3 секунд
    </script>
...
</head>
```

Или на PHP:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", true);
header("Refresh: 3;url=https://yandex.ru", true);

echo "Page not found";
```